# Use of callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function from a class to another in javascript. 
This function takes as parameter an other function.
I receive a syntax error, do you know where it is ?
Here is the error I receive :

> ./src/containers/NewNote.js
>     Line 53:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

51 |     try {
  52 |       const attachment = this.file

> 53 |         ? await s3Upload(this.file, this.inputValue, onUpdate() => {
>        |                                                                 ^
>     54 |           this.setState({progress: progress});
>     55 |         }
>     56 |         )

The function I want to call is the following :

```
export async function s3Upload(file, header, onUpdate) {
  filename = 'toto';
  const stored = await Storage.vault.put(filename, file, {
    progressCallback(progress) {
      var percentage = (progress.loaded / progress.total * 100).toFixed(0);
      console.log(`Uploaded: ${percentage}%`, onUpdate);
      if (typeof onUpdate === "function") {
        try {
          onUpdate(percentage);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error("Error while computing update", e);
        }
      }
    },
    contentType: file.type
  });

  return stored.key;
}
```

And the calling function is the following :

```
try {
  const attachment = this.file ?
    await s3Upload(this.file, this.inputValue, onUpdate() => {
      this.setState({
        progress: progress
      });
    }) :
    null;

  await this.createNote({
    attachment,
    content: this.state.content
  });
  window.location.href = "/"
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
  this.setState({
    isLoading: false
  });
}
```

And

```
this.state = {
  isLoading: null,
  content: "",
  progress: null
};
```

Comment: Where is the problem or the question?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error I can see is the following:

```
onUpdate() => {
  this.setState({
    progress: progress
  });
}
```

It should be:

```
(progress) => {
  this.setState({
    progress: progress
  });
}
```

The reason for this is that there are neither named parameters, which this would not be, nor named [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), meaning that you cannot name your arrow function in this case.
Additionally, you will have to add a parameter, in this case `progress` to your arrow function as you use it in the code of that function and also pass it to the callback.

Comment: Thanks, will this function call match the call to onUpdate in the s3Upload() function ?

Comment: @cocool97 You will have to specify a parameter `(progress) => ..`. Check my updated answer.